# Does Java based Quartz scheduler supports OpenTracing?

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, opentracing

I am looking if quartz(Java Based) supports OpenTracing or not. I have tried to find out but no luck yet. Any lead would be helpful. I am using below library for quartz

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```